# Is there any way to match and change a variable in a data frame by its index in a different data frame in R?

Tags: r, match

I have the following setup of data:

```r
Address= paste(letters)
Lon= runif(26,-4.392 ,-3.266)
Lat= runif(26, 39.86, 40.93 )
Data <- data.frame(Address,Lon,Lat)

head(Data)
  Address       Lon      Lat
1       a -3.753748 40.11277
2       b -3.951202 40.28311
3       c -4.042915 40.82732
4       d -3.731300 40.18065
5       e -3.584044 39.86653
6       f -3.903482 40.33516
```

I intend to find the first 5 nearest neighbours of each point

```r
nearest = nn2(Data[,c(-1)],Data[,c(-1)], 6) ## find the nearest neighbour 
n_data = as.data.frame(nearest$nn.idx) ## extract the nn index
```

the result is the following data frame (n_data)

```r
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  4 22 24  2  6
2  2  6 23 10  4  1
3  3 20 11 26 18  9
4  4  1 22 24  6  2
5  5 22 13  1  4 16
6  6  2 10 23  4 24
```

in which every Variable is representing and Address (a,b,c....)

I want to match those index in n_data, to the ones in Data, so the table looks like this

```r
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  a  d  v  x  b  f
2  b  f  w  j  d  a
...........
```

as far as I get is doing it by rows matching the two data frames

```r
Data[as.numeric(n_data[1,]),1]
```

any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you can "recode" vectors to their labels (e.g. address) in the following way. Just make sure that you have enough labels for the possible values in your real case example.

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,2,5)
address <- letters[1:6]

#-------- recode
address[vec]
```

This will give you the vector with the associated labels.

```
> address[vec]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "d" "e" "f" "b" "e"
```

Use this principle for manipulating your dataframe.

**data**

```
library(dplyr)

Address= paste(letters)
n_data <- tibble::tribble(
     ~V1, ~V2, ~V3, ~V4, ~V5, ~V6,
  1,  4, 22, 24,  2,  6,
  2,  6, 23, 10,  4,  1,
  3, 20, 11, 26, 18,  9,
  4,  1, 22, 24,  6,  2,
  5, 22, 13,  1,  4, 16,
  6,  2, 10, 23,  4, 24
  )
```

**example coding**

For example, we "recode" your 6th column V6 as follows:

```
Address[n_data$V6]
[1] "f" "a" "i" "b" "p" "x"
```

**applying it to your dataframe**

"by hand" - you would assign the recoded address values to the same column of define a new one (to your liking). The following "overwrites" column V1.
Obviously, you could do the assignments Vx = ... multiple times inside the `mutate()`. With below there is a more elegant way of doing this.

```
n_data %>% mutate(V1 = Address[V1])
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  V1       V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         4    22    24     2     6
2 b         6    23    10     4     1
3 c        20    11    26    18     9
4 d         1    22    24     6     2
5 e        22    13     1     4    16
6 f         2    10    23     4    24
```

The package `{dplyr}` has a neat `across()` helper function that allows you to execute the same operation across a series of columns.
The recoding of your columns is such an application case.

To run the decoding we specify a so-called anonymous function, i.e. `function(x){ does-something-and-returns-a-single-value }`. In our case we use the aforementioned principle `outervector[subsetted-by-inner-vector]`.

```
n_data %>% mutate(
   across(.cols = V1:V6                    # specify the cols you want to use
         , .fns = function(x){Address[x]}  # define operation
         )
  )
```

This yields your recoded dataframe:

```
  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     d     v     x     b     f    
2 b     f     w     j     d     a    
3 c     t     k     z     r     i    
4 d     a     v     x     f     b    
5 e     v     m     a     d     p    
6 f     b     j     w     d     x
```

Comment: Thanks! is very helpful, yet for the real case the labels should correspond to a pair of vectors (e.g Lat, Lon or x,y) so the method you are describing would only work for one. Or there is a way it can work on two vectors?

Comment: @Nicolas_ind_ I updated my answer to apply it to your example. Sorry, if my earlier response was to brief on how to do this. To be frank, I do not understand your comment. You problem - at least what I understood - is to recode a vector of labels to numeric values. Thus, you want to find a:=1, x:=24, etc. That your labels a,b,etc are geographic positions of 2 vectors, i.e. LAT, LON, is already embedded in the label. Obviously, you need to have a vector of all numerical neighbour values and a same length vector of labels for each of the possible neighbour values. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Ray, that was exactly what I needed.